# Reversing the order of a list without using inbuilt functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and in trying to get better I purchased some textbooks. One problem I found in a textbook has me really confused as I feel the solution is obvious. I am given a insertion sort code that orders a list in ascending order. The problem asks to reverse the order of the list (so it is descending) without using in built functions and instead altering the code. Here is the code:

```
sequence = [5,-2,0,6,10,-5,1]


def myInsertionSort(sequence):
    for i in range (1, len(sequence)):
        item = sequence[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and sequence[j-1] > item:
            sequence[j] = sequence[j-1]
            j -= 1
            sequence[j] = item
    return sequence

myInsertionSort(sequence)
```

I added an example sequence and the output here is that it orders the sequence in ascending order. I realised the key here was to understand the code, so I used pythontutor.com to visualise and understand each step, and even though I now feel I understand it every edit I make to the code results in an error or un-ordered list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking us for. Do you have a specific question? "... every edit I make to the code results in an error or un-ordered list." <- Can you show us those errors, and explain what the expected output would be here? Your code also claims to do insertion sort, but that's not what your description and title suggest you're trying to do.

Comment: What is your main question? You want to learn, so we probably should not just give you a working code. Please describe at what step you do not understand how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: to sort in *ascending* order, two elements `a` and `b` are considered out of order when `a > b`. But if you want to sort in *descending* order, `a > b` means they are already in the correct position.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, my question is how I can change this code so that it outputs a sorted list in descending order without using inbuilt functions. When I try to alter the code the list I am getting is just un-ordered. Thank you.

Comment: Why reverse it when you should have simply sorted it correctly in the first place? This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Swift It's an *exercise*.

Comment: Funnily enough, that makes more sense lol

Answer (score 0):

Consider this slight generalization of your code; I've just refactored the comparison of `sequence[j-1]` and `item` to a separate function.

```
def out_of_order(a, b):
    return a > b

def myInsertionSort(sequence):
    for i in range (1, len(sequence)):
        item = sequence[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and out_of_order(sequence[j-1], item):
            sequence[j] = sequence[j-1]
            j -= 1
            sequence[j] = item
    return sequence
```

The `while` loop swaps two items if they are considered out of order. Now think about what happens if you change what it means for two items to be out of order by modifying the definition of `out_of_order`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense and I can build on this :)

Comment: What's wrong with splicing? You can do it in one line

Comment: @Swift What do you mean?

Comment: The question isn't "How do I reverse a list?", it's "How do I modify the given insertion-sort implementation to sort in decreasing order?"

Comment: Well to be fair if you read the title, it's a little mis-leading and gives false context to the rest of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your book example is not very pythonic.

This is called **insertion sort**. It may help to see how it works with an animation.  Take a look at this website (make sure to select insertion [**INS**] sort): https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting

That be said keep a close eye on the `>` in the while loop statement `sequence[j-1] > item`. That is my hint.

```
sequence = [5,-2,0,6,10,-5,1]


def myInsertionSort(sequence):
    for i in range (1, len(sequence)):
        item = sequence[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and sequence[j-1] < item:
            sequence[j] = sequence[j-1]
            j -= 1
            sequence[j] = item
    return sequence

myInsertionSort(sequence)
```

If it makes it easier to read, here is there example written a little differently:

```
sequence = [5,-2,0,6,10,-5,1]

def myInsertionSort(sequence):
    for j in range (1, len(sequence)):
        while j > 0 and sequence[j-1] > sequence[j]:
            sequence[j], sequence[j-1] = sequence[j-1], sequence[j] # Flip the elements
            j -= 1 # Move down one index
    return sequence

print(myInsertionSort(sequence))
```

Comment: Thank you, all comments have cleared this up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way is simply to return sequence[::-1] and it will give you an ascending ordered list. I don't consider list reverse technique as in-built-function.

```
return sequence[::-1]
```

But if you think that it counts, here is the alternative code:

```
sequence = [5,-2,0,6,10,-5,1]


def myInsertionSort(sequence):
    for i in range (1, len(sequence)):
        item = sequence[i] # for example, when i is 0, item = 5
        j = i # now j = i = 1
        while j > 0 and sequence[j-1] < item:
        # our goal is to push smaller numbers towards the end of the list
        # e.g. when i = 1, j = 1 sequence[j-1] = sequence[0] = 5, so sequence[0] > sequence[1], we want to keep their position, now move on
        #. when i = 1, j = 2, sequence[j-1] = sequence[1] = -2, so sequence[1] < sequence[2], we must switch them
            sequence[j] = sequence[j-1] # sequence[1] is reassigned the current value of sequence[2] because the latter is bigger
            j -= 1 # now we also must put the smaller value in the current sequence[2] position  
            sequence[j] = item # sequence[2] = item (item is the sequence[1]) 
    return sequence

myInsertionSort(sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you, very easy to understand :)